# Page breaks appearing as thick line on actual print-out

Tags: front-end, notebooks

I'm using Insert->Page Break to do just that, but thick black lines are appearing on the actual printed copy wherever I indicated a break. Can this be turned off?

Comment: What kind of printing environment do you have selected?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries I'm using Bulleted Environment with Outline as the stylesheet.

Comment: Don't know that. Are you sure you're looking at [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/PrintingEnvironment.html) or [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/menuitem/PrintingSettings.html)?

Comment: Could you try with the default stylesheet and printing settings?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've looked through both and tried with the default stylesheet. The problem is still there :(

Comment: In the working environment page breaks appear as black lines, if I'm not mistaken. It looks like the print is emulating the working environment. I'll check what may be causing this when I'm back at my own Mathematica installation.

Comment: I can confirm that this also happens to me in the default stylesheet. Perhaps you should contact support@wolfram.com to make a bug report. As a workaround I suggest using cells with "\f" (form feed). Evaluate an input cell with it and copy the resulting output cell anywhere you want to have a page break.

Comment: That's a really good idea! I'll give that a try. If you submit your last comment as an answer, I'd be glad to give you best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this also happens to me in the default stylesheet. Perhaps you should contact support@wolfram.com to file a bug report. As a workaround I suggest using cells with "\f" (form feed). Evaluate an input cell with it and copy the resulting output cell anywhere you want to have a page break.

Comment: Do you mind posting the actual BoxData of the cell.  I have been trying `CellPrint@Cell[BoxData["\<\"\\f\"\>"], "Output"]` with no luck so far.

Comment: @LiamWilliam I used this trick quite long ago. It must have been version 5. Indeed, it doesn't seem to work in more recent version.

Comment: The following workaround appears to work in M9.  `Cell["", "Input", PageBreakBelow -> True, CellOpen->False ]`

Comment: In addition I can't seem to repeat the original issue posted in M9 so the workaround may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to suppress the black line you can change this in the Style Sheet.  For a particular Notebook choose **Format > Edit Stylesheet...** and paste this into the window:

```
Cell[StyleData["PageBreak", "Printout"],
 Editable->False,
 CellFrame->0,
 CellMargins->{{0, 0}, {1, 1}},
 CellElementSpacings->{"CellMinHeight"->1,
 "ClosedCellHeight"->1},
 CellOpen->False,
 PageBreakBelow->True,
 CellFrameMargins->0,
 CellSize->{Inherited, 2},
 Background->None]
```

Choose **Yes** if asked "Do you want to interpret the text?".  Nothing will appear because the style is invisible (that's the idea after all) but it will have effect.  Close the Style Sheet.

Linebreaks in this Notebook will now be invisible in the "Printout" environment (the default for printing and PDF export).

If you want to apply this to all new Notebooks you can create a custom Style Sheet and then change the global `DefaultStyleDefinitions` option to point to it:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hey. Thank you for the answer, but the problem is still there. I've tentatively solved the problem by manually adding new lines. Not elegant, unfortunately.

Comment: @user745434 when using the method presented to you still see the black dividing lines on the screen in Screen Environment > Printout, or only on paper?

Comment: only on paper. Just now I realized that printout is also a screen environment (sorry, new guy). I was referring to the paper itself (also print preview, saved PDFs, etc.)

Comment: @user okay, I haven't tried printing to paper.  I'll see if I can find a solution that affects that too but it will have to wait.